# Group Homomorphism over the real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I currently encountered the following functional equation:
$f(x^y)=yf(x)$,
$x\in \mathbb{R^+}$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$
The solutions to this equation are any Group Homomorphism $\Phi:(R^+,\cdot)\to(R,+)$. (Is that correct?)
The only solution I was able to find so far is $\Phi(x)=a\cdot\ln{x}, a\in R$
which also includes the trivial Homomorphism (a=0).
Do you know any other such Homomorphisms?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: True, but the question remains for x>0

Comment: There are more such homomorphisms, but they are nasty. Namely, we may compose $\text{ln}(x)$ with any homomorphism of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to itself to obtain a new, different homomorphism. These maps are classified by the solutions to Cauchy's functional equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation. There are the obvious solutions, but also many ugly ones

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful!

Comment: Any continuous group homomorphism is an exemplar $f$. I think ‘wild’ discontinuous group homomorphisms might exist that are not actually solutions. The homomorphism condition only gives you the functional equation for rational $y$